# Send mail in Java Bean with html tags

Tags: java, javabeans, oracle-data-integrator

I am trying to fetch some data from oracle database, and trying to send a mail. I want the rows and columns to fit in a table structure. So i was thinking of an HTML table. How can I do the same in the `Java Bean` itself. Here is my code:

```
<@
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;

conn=odiRef.getJDBCConnection("SRC");
Statement stmt=conn.createStatement();
String result="";
char delimiter=(char)9;
String line="";
result+="SESS_NAME"+delimiter+"STEP_NO"+delimiter+"SESS_STATUS"+delimiter+"SESSION_END_TIME"+delimiter+"SESSION_DURATION"+(char)13;

my_query="select * from odi_mon";
ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(my_query);
ResultSetMetaData md=rs.getMetaData();
int numColumns =md.getColumnCount();

for(int j=0;j<70;j++){
    line+="_";
}
result+=line+(char)13;

while (rs.next()) {
    for (int i=1; i<numColumns+1; i++) {
        String  output=rs.getString(md.getColumnName(i))+delimiter;
        result+=output;
    }
result=result.substring(0,result.length()-1);  
result+=line+(char)13;
result+=(char)13;
}
// Close Connection
stmt.close();
conn.close();
@>
```

Comment: What is the output youre getting or what exactly you need help with? To get your code fixed? Why are you appending 70 underscores to your line? A lot of crazy stuff going on in there yet you provided very little information. Please try harder just throwing a code block out there.